# Changing the font of a document using a select dropdown in javascript

Tags: javascript, select, drop-down-menu, font-family

I am trying to figure out how to make this work. Please let me know if there is something I can change to make this code work without changing it completely.

```
<select name="fontPick">
<option value="0">Font</option>
<option value="1">Calibri</option>
<option value="2">Candara</option>
<option value="3">Tahoma</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
document.querySelector('[name="fontPick"]').addEventListener('change', function () {
    var fonts = this.options[this.selectedIndex].textContent;
    document.body.style.fontFamily = fonts;
});
</script>
```

Comment: your code seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/4sfdegrm/

Comment: You were right.  It works when I test it in Chrome.  I was testing in Firefox before and it would not work.

Answer (score 0):

`<script type="text/javascript>` you forgot the closing `"` make it
`<script type="text/javascript">`